# Downloading PDF content from a website -

Tags: c#

I'm trying to download a PDF to my desktop - The PDF updates about every couple days with new content, and I was trying to see if there is a way to have the PDF automatically update its self when it has fresh content without having to go to the actual link.

-- http://www.uakron.edu/dotAsset/1265971.pdf

Comment: Erm, you cannot find out *anything* if you don't want to 'go to the actual link'.

Comment: Uhm, I'm trying to download the PDF and create a script that will automatically get all the updates by itself without having to go to the link.

Comment: Instead of programming your own script, you could use wget and a cron job (or the windows equivalent of it). Earlier Windows versions (98 I think) had a feature that could actually do this, but I suspect it has been removed.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is *even remotely* a programming question, you could try a HTTP HEAD query (ideally sending a If-Modified-Since header in your request), and inspect the response headers - if the server is friendly, it'll tell you whether it hasn't been updated via a 304 response code.

If you don't get a 304, then issue a GET request and save the response stream.

You could also just try issuing a GET with last-modified (skipping the HEAD); but a HEAD request might save some bandwidth if the server isn't entirely happy with just a GET / 304.

Not tested extensively, but:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string url = "http://www.uakron.edu/dotAsset/1265971.pdf", localPath = "1265971.pdf";

        var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        req.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
        req.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding","gzip,deflate");
        if(File.Exists(localPath))
            req.IfModifiedSince = File.GetLastWriteTimeUtc(localPath);
        try
        {
            using (var resp = req.GetResponse())
            {
                int len;
                checked
                {
                    len = (int)resp.ContentLength;
                }
                using (var file = File.Create(localPath))
                using (var data = resp.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[4 * 1024];
                    int bytesRead;
                    while (len > 0 && (bytesRead = data.Read(buffer, 0, Math.Min(len, buffer.Length))) > 0)
                    {
                        len -= bytesRead;
                        file.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("New version downloaded");
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            if (ex.Response == null || ex.Status != WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
                throw;
            Console.WriteLine("Not updated");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marc! I appreciate it. Can you provide me with a link of trying to do something like this? I have no idea how I would go about coding this up.

Comment: @Blake - I've tested that url, and it doesn't seem to support much of this (pretty standard stuff); however, things like `WebClient` or `HtpWebRequest` are your friend here.

Comment: Oh, wow! Thank you Marc! I appreciate that you wrote that out for me. I'm going to go over it with detail. Thanks :)